# Is there a real-life advantage of mixed lists

Tags: python, list

I have worked with C# and Java and everytime I needed a List I wanted to store objects of the same type, like:

```
List<Customer> customers; 
//or
List<Invoice> invoices;
```

The [official Python-Doc](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) states:

> Lists might contain items of different types, but usually the items all have the same type.

Therefore this is possible:

```
list = [1, 2, 3, "cat", some_object, "another cat", 4, "and a cat again"]
```

There are hundreds of examples of mixed lists and explanations of why it is possible.
I **understand** why it is possible in python to have lists with mixed types but I cannot think of an **real life example** where it would be useful.

I am wondering for quite some time if there is a real advantage of having mixed lists.
Or is it just: **"we don't need it, but we can!"**

Am I missing something very important about mixed lists which would make me a better python-programmer?

**Edit:**
I thought this answer will be given that python cant do otherwise so let me rephrase that:

Or is it just: **"we don't need it, but we can't do otherwise!"**

Comment: [Cross site duplicate](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/132835/is-there-a-specific-purpose-for-heterogeneous-lists)

Comment: I don't really understand the question. Sometimes I need to store collections of different types of things, sometimes I need to store collections of the same type of thing. Either way, I use a list.

Comment: @DanielRoseman `Sometimes I need to store collections of different types of things`. Thats the question.... what is an example of such a situation

Comment: Off the top of my head, the values of the columns in a row in my db table. Or the arguments passed to a function using the `*args` syntax. Or anything.

Comment: Recently I needed a list with no value defined for some indexes, so I used `None`. I needed a list with both `int` and `NoneType` (ex: `[1,3,2,None,4,None,1]`).

Comment: You could have a simple tree, a list containing lists and some objects

Comment: JSON regularly mixes dictionaries and lists. I can't imagine having to arrange them homogenously.

Comment: So we have `*args`, `database-columns`, `JSON-Objects`, `tree-like structures`. I have not thought of them all. If someone wants to wrap that into an answer, there are some points to gain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, as referenced in the above-linked [cross-site question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/132835/is-there-a-specific-purpose-for-heterogeneous-lists), remember that a language like Java will let you create an array of `Object` anyway, which is pretty similar to Python's default `list`.

Second, there is an extremely common use case for data structures containing elements of different types. Here's an example:

```
def get_row():
    response = input('Enter your name and score, separated by a space: ').split()
    return response[0], int(response[1])
```

Now you're returning a `tuple` that contains a string and an integer.

Here's another example:

```
names = ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie']
scores = [8, 12, 9]
results = dict(zip(names, scores))
```

Without being able to create `tuple`s with a string and an integer, we might have to do something like `results = {name:scores[i] for i, name in enumerate(names)}`. Could we? Sure... but it's nice that we can choose the one that looks better, without even having to think about whether our data structure holds `str` or `int` or `object`, and without having to cast `object`s before the compiler will allow us to work with them.

Answer (score 5):

Python lists store items of the same type -- references to other objects.

> Or is it just: "we don't need it, but we can!"

No it's not. Python doesn't have type checking, so it's rather "because we can't do otherwise".

Comment: As I stated I understand how python works it contained that I understand, that python can't do otherwise. You still gave no answer to my question **IF** there is an advantage.

Comment: > if there is a real advantage of having mixed lists < There are some [general advantages](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/132835/is-there-a-specific-purpose-for-heterogeneous-lists) (taken from the comments), but in Python the question doesn't make much sense, because you have no language  constraints.

Answer (score 0):

It has applications cause polymorphism. Imagine you have multiple sports objects, like `socker`, `basketball` and `football`, each one is played different but all are played, so you can say

```
socker = Socker()
basketball = Basketball()
football = Football()
sportsILike = [socker, basketball, football]
for sport in sportsILike:
    sport.play()
```

The interesting thing is that those sports are different classes!